# image is not displaying in HTML, when rendered from python api

Tags: javascript, python, html, endpoint, html-rendering

**Controller code:-**

```
@controller.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

---

**index.html:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
h2  {text-align: center;}
div {text-align: center;}
p   {text-align: center;}

#container
{
    margin-top : 25px;
<!--   width:100%-->
}
    </style>
<title>
MY-Pulse
</title>
</head>
<script src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
<body>
<img src="img1.png" alt="img1" width="170" height="170" align="left">
<img src="img2.png" alt="img2" width="220" height="170" align="right">
<br>
<br><br><br>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="text-muted" align="middle">Heading</h1>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Both img1 and img2 are there in the templates folder, when the api is hit the images are not loading and displaying like

[image after hitting the endpoint you can see the images are not loaded over there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaC9e.png)

[Console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Xtk.png)

Comment: What are the console logs from the browser and or logs from Python saying? I'm sure there would be some clue for those images not displaying.

Comment: Please find the photo of the console logs in the edited question

Comment: what are your Python logs saying?